# Why was past perfect used here instead of past simple?

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

I came across these two sentences while reading *F. Paul Wilson - Gateways*:

> But what Jack really **seemed** to enjoy most was reading far-out fiction and watching old sci-fi and monster movies.
> His father **had worried** about Jack, urging him into more social activities. ...

I cannot understand why the author didn't use just "**worried**" instead of "**had worried**". I don't think the author wanted to say that the father's worrying was before the period in the past in which Jack seemed to enjoy. What exactly was emphasized by "**had worried**" and what difference would have been if the author had used just "**worried**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> His father **had worried** about Jack, urging him into more social activities. ...

Past perfect because Jack's father worried about him in the past, but the action has stopped now. The subtle difference would have been that the action might be reckoned to have been continued in the then future.

Comment: Similarly, Jack also seemed to enjoy in the past, but why was past simple used there?

Comment: Might be he is still enjoying it.

Comment: The use of past perfect is nearly deprecated now. Most people when speaking or writing confuse between the two of them and simply use whichever sounds the best in the context among other choices.